# Passing variables through byref or declaring them global?

Tags: vb.net, variables, global, byref

I'm dividing a large piece of code into many different functions, however, I am encountering a problem where I am not sure if I should pass variables through ByRef or declare them global. Which one would you recommend and in what conditions is one better than the other?

Along with this, I'm wondering if I declare a variable in my primary loading sub if it will be available to other functions called from the sub or if it is necessary to declare them globally in the class.

Comment: If its scope is applicable throughout class make it global variable, on the other hand if its scope is limited to sub itself pass it to the sub.

Comment: Only value type variables need to be passed ByRef to allow them to be changed.   If you declare a CLASS, though, then that Class can hold multiple value types and you can simply pass a reference to that single instance of that class using ByVal, and the values within can be changed.